# Review of Low Quality Posts

Tags: support, review

I reviewed a post, where I thought, recommending it for deletion with the option "This is a different question posted as an answer" is a good idea. I found that someone else was already the same opinion as me, since the corresponding comment showed up.

Is it ok to upvote the other comment and choose "Looks good" or should I independently recommend deletion?

Comment: Where does the corresponding comment show up? You mean as a comment to the post itself? In that case I think it'd be better to independently recommend deletion.

Comment: Below the post you'll get: "If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context." Will it add another copy of this standard comment when I also recommend deletion?

Comment: Ah, you mean that you saw evidence that someone else has already reviewed the post and recommended deletion? Sorry I misunderstood your OP. (I thought you meant that someone just commented independently of the reviewing process that the post is not an answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [/review queue - Duplicate automatic comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156409/review-queue-duplicate-automatic-comments) if the comment already exists it is supposed to automatically upvote the existing one.  (Though as the link above showed, there may be some bugs in that feature.) So I think you should go ahead and recommend deletion and not worry about what other users have thought.