# Why do posts show up in low-quality post review queue multiple times?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

Why do posts show up in low-quality post review queue multiple times? Based on this [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/review-of-low-quality-posts) it seems to suggest that this isn't a bug. What is the point of multiple high/medium rep users reviewing the same post?

Comment: Whether or not a post should be considered low quality is a very subjective question. What's the harm in getting many different users to give an opinion on the issue and only delete a post if it accumulates sufficiently many votes recommending deletion?